# use a true regex for a special url not working in htaccess

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have this url:

https://www.example.com/product/abcde595-556/?customize_changeset_uuid=b7fa6e4c-aa67-49c3-a08a-893c57d81b18&customize_autosaved=on

and I want redirect above url to :

https://www.example.com/product/abcde595-556/

I write this regex that worked in regex testing tools but not working in htaccess:

```
^(.*)\?
```

My htaccess code is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\? $1 [R=301,L]
```

please help me and tell why not working that's regex

Comment: Is your query string is dynamically generated?

Answer (score 3):

The query string is usually NOT part of the URL that the Rewrite Engine matches, so your RewriteRule tries to match something that is not there.

I think you are searching for the option [QSD](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) with redirects, that removes the query string:

```
# Turn ReriteEngine On
RewriteEngine On

# Only apply rewrite if query string is set
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .

# do the rewrite
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=301,QSD,L]
```

*(htaccess is untested)*

Comment: The query string is of course part of the URL; a bit more precise way of phrasing it would be: RewriteRule matches against the path component of the URL only. (And the relative path, at that.)

Comment: Sure. My wording was bad/incomplete. Fixed it. Thanks ;)